# C# List<> to xml

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

Calling

```
List<PC> _PCList = new List<PC>();
...add Pc to PCList.. 
WriteXML<List<PC>>(_PCList, "ss.xml");
```

Function

```
public static void WriteXML<T>(T o, string filename)
{

    string filePath= Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\Genweb2\\ADSnopper\\" + filename;

    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    XPathNavigator nav = xmlDoc.CreateNavigator();
    using (XmlWriter writer = nav.AppendChild())
    {
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>), new XmlRootAttribute("TheRootElementName"));
        ser.Serialize(writer, o); // error
    }
    File.WriteAllText(filePath,xmlDoc.InnerXml);

}
```

inner exception

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[PC]' to type 
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[PC]]'.

Please Help

Comment: Dont forget to upvote and mark it as accepted if it work for you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with the line

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>), ...
```

Your `T` is already `List<PC>`, and you're trying to create `typeof(List<T>)`, which will translate to `typeof(List<List<PC>>)`. Simply make it `typeof(T)` instead.

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
typeof(T)
```

instead of

```
List<T> 

XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), new XmlRootAttribute("TheRootElementName"));
```

Answer (score 1):

this line in your code causing problem

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>),
```

its creating list of list than is not needed

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T),
```

**either you do above change or do  below changes**

There is problem with you method you need to change signature to

```
public static void WriteXML<T>(List<T> o, string filename)
```

and call method as below

```
WriteXML<PC>(_PCList, "ss.xml");
```

By doing above change might resolve your issue.